# Need a javascript function in return of Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to get the javascript function in ajax call. My code works fine and returning back my javascript code but there is a problem in my received javascript function. Here is my code for Ajax..

```
function media_type(id)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {   
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
        else
        {   
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    eval(document.getElementById("asad").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","video/media_type.php?cat_id="+id,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

And her is the code where i am returning a simple hello world alert box.

```
    if($num_rows==0)
    {
    //echo("Sorry no record found.");

    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("hello World");
                </script>';
    }
```

I am receiving the code back exactly but code is not executing. Please tell me how i can fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I have yet to see an `eval()` used like this.

Comment: i want to get back the alertbox("hello world") through Ajax call. Actually i want to execute a code that has Javascript in it.

Comment: i want to get returned this code echo("alert('hello World')");

Answer (score 1):

Can I ask why you need to return JavaScript from the server? How about you return a simple response (string, boolean, number) from the server, and execute something that already lives on the client based on the return value? Much safer and easier. It may not be the solution you are looking for, but your js-fu will be much stronger for it.

Comment: hi Eli,Thanks for your quick response actually i want to use JWplayer instead of helloworld! jw player contains a javascript code in it. is there any other solution for execution. I am retrieving the Url through Database table then assigning the path to my Javascript.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't store this on the front-end instead of a database?

Comment: yes i am uploading videos remotely in database that's why i need to store these in database. I have more than  500 links currently that's why i can't store these on front end.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue the other day...

you have to set your header in the php page to Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8

Here is the Entire Code to make this work

For your php file

```
<?php 
header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8");
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("hello World");
            </script>
      ';?>
```

and here is the Javascript

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'toget.php',
        success:function(d)
        {
            $(document).append(d);
        }
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your quick response but i could not found the solution by adopting this method

Comment: Hi thanks i highly appreciate your effort i am using this code<?php 
  header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8"); 
  echo'<html>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  alert("hello World"); 
  </script> 
  </html>'; ?> but still no alert box is there. i am receiving the code as it is back... I want to execute this code

Comment: Still i am unable to execute the alertbox.. Function returns this code<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("hello World");
            </script> while when i use eval i can get the output in my required div. but there is only a single issue remains code is being displayed as it is in div but not executing correctly. But in your solution My required div is not receiving any output.

Comment: the code i put will execute any javascript that you want.. if you want to add the text from the php file into the div it should be plain text and not js.. or you could have the js write itself into the desired div...

Comment: Thanks can you explain it further i am sharing complete code with you.here is my div where i want to get back this code in execution <div id="mydiv"></div>and here is my ajax function function media_type(id)
 {
  //some code here  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
      eval(document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText);
     }
    }

Comment: my file media_type.php has following piece of code for execution in return<?php
  $id = $_GET['cat_id'];
  $q ="select * from media_author where cat_id='$id'";
  $rs=mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
  $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($rs);
  if($num_rows==0)
  {
  //echo("Sorry no record found.");
  
  
//echo("Sorry no record found.");
 echo'<html><script type="text/javascript">
            alert("hello World");
            </script>
      </html>';}

Comment: here is my complete code please check this code and let me where we have problem. And how we can fix this issue. Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

i will try with this

```
if($num_rows==0)
{
//echo("Sorry no record found.");
 echo'<html><script type="text/javascript">
            alert("hello World");
            </script>
      </html>';
}
```

i think this line is creating problem

```
eval(document.getElementById("asad").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText)
```

that is

```
eval(document.getElementById("asad").innerHTML='<script>alert("Hi");</script>';)
```

getting converted to

```
eval(document.getElementById("asad").innerHTML='&lt; script &gt; alert("Hi");&lt;/script&gt;';)
```

Comment: give this a try -> sourceforge.net/projects/ajax-micro-mini/

Comment: I have used this code but i am sorry to say problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Just return the JS that you want to execute (`alert("hello World");`) and make an `eval`. Remove `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>`

`eval(xmlhttp.responseText);`

will be:

`eval('alert("hello World")');`

Comment: I was afraid `eval` was going to come up in this question.

Comment: hi jotapdiez, Thanks for your response i think my problem in near to be solved. Now i am getting this output in my Div  alert('hello world'); But i want to execute an alert box.. Thanks again....

Answer (score -1):

```
//try using this
<?php
  if($num_rows==0)
    {

    //echo("Sorry no record found.");
?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("hello World");
            </script>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps a little description of your code would help future viewers of this question.